# SCSSPHP Compiler: parse error at `&} {` in mixins\_badge.scss and _badge.scss from bootstrap

Tags: php, css, sass

If I try to compile my scss files which includes bootstrap (scss), then I've got an parse error

```
'parse error: failed at `&}` /mypath/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_badge.scss on line 5' (132 chars)
```

and

```
'parse error: failed at `&} {` /mypath/scss/bootstrap/_badge.scss on line 17' (128 chars)
```

It's working if I comment it out. I'm using the SCSSPHP Compiler.

mixins_badge.scss:

```
@at-root a#{&} {
    @include hover-focus {
      color: color-yiq($bg);
      background-color: darken($bg, 10%);
    }
}
```

and the same issue at _badge.scss:

```
@at-root a#{&} {
  @include hover-focus {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `a#{&}`? That part seems wrong.

Comment: this is wrong syntax a#{&}

Comment: okay, then there's a bug in bootstrapp sass files, that's the code from bootstrap, not mine.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_badge.scss

Comment: I just checked and it seems that the problem comes from scssphp. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/leafo/scssphp/issues/614#issuecomment-450867551) about it.

Comment: okay thank you, hope they will fix it soon

Comment: Confirmed, it is fixed in the current latest version (v 1.1.1) v1.1.1 link https://github.com/scssphp/scssphp/releases/tag/1.1.1 `or generic latest is on https://github.com/scssphp/scssphp/releases/latest`